# file_get_html() not working?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the title and meta description data of page by providing it url of target page but file_get_html() always return FALSE value.
Any suggestions? by the way I have enabled the php extension php_openssl.

```
<?php
    include("inc/simple_html_dom.inc.php");
    $contents = file_get_html("https://www.facebook.com"); 
    if($contents !=FALSE) //always skips if condition
    {
        foreach($contents->find('title') as $element) 
        {
            $title = $element->plaintext;
        }

        foreach($contents->find('meta[description]') as $element) 
        {
            $meta_description = $element->plaintext;
        }
        $output = array('title'=>$title, 'meta'=> $meta_description);
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    else
    {
        echo"Couldn't load contents";
    }
?>
```

UPDATE:

So file_get_html() works fine now but any idea about dealing with facebook update browser message?

Comment: you should use file_get_contents()

Comment: @BurhanÇetin thank you for your response but that would display "update browser message" of facebook and I wouldn't be able to get accurate title. Any other suggestions?

Comment: file_get_html() is not a PHP built in function, so we cannot tell why it is returning FALSE. What is the source code of file_get_html() ?

Comment: Also, does your network or system require a proxy? PHP by default does not use the system proxy and tries to connect directly.

Comment: @MichaelButler Hello Micahel thank you for your response, file_get_html() is a function of PHP simple html dom parser, and I am not using any proxy server so I guess it wouldn't be problem related to proxy.

Comment: Could you try it first with a simple page that is not https? maybe http://www.wikipedia.org. Also see Sean Bright's solution below

Comment: @MichaelButler using normal protocol is fine too but the problem is browser update message, and yes Sean Bright's solution is excellent but I think I am lacking any resource or extension due to which I getting error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    /* 
     * XXX: This is not a "fix" for your problem, this is a work-around.  You 
     * should fix your local CAs 
     */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    /* Set a browser UA so that we aren't told to update */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36');

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($res === false) {
        die('error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    $d = new DOMDocument();
    @$d->loadHTML($res);

    $output = array(
        'title' => '',
        'meta'  => ''
    );

    $x = new DOMXPath($d);

    $title = $x->query("//title");
    if ($title->length > 0) {
        $output['title'] = $title->item(0)->textContent;
    }

    $meta = $x->query("//meta[@name = 'description']");
    if ($meta->length > 0) {
        $output['meta'] = $meta->item(0)->getAttribute('content');
    }

    print_r($output);
?>
```

This displays:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More
    [meta] => Facebook is a social utility that connects people with friends and others who work, study and live around them. People use Facebook to keep up with friends, upload an unlimited number of photos, post links and videos, and learn more about the people they meet.
)
```

Comment: thank you for your efforts, using https: I get the following error:
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

whereas using http:// returns null title and meta tag, any idea?

Comment: Are you using any additional extensions other than php_openssl in your PHP version?

Comment: Sounds like your local authority files are missing or out of date.  You should correct that issue.  To work around it for development purposes, you can set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false, although this is dangerous.  See my update