# websites Parsing uisng simple html dom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

[when we get the file_get_html() show this output.not fully loaded the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL236.png)I have used simple html dom for website scraping but some website can load the context web pages, but one of my website cannot load? 
 my webite that cannot load `https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/`  what can we do thanks.

```
include('../simple_html_dom1.php');
$opts  = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "User-Agent:USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36".
                "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html= file_get_html('https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/',FALSE,$context);
echo $html;
exit;
```

Comment: What have you already tried, and why did that not work?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198911/2275490 maybe it helps

Comment: my code successfully run and file_get_html() request is working in many website .but  this website cannot load web pages https://shop.advanceautoparts.com.

Comment: @Stratadox  i have tried this code.this code is working for many website but one website => https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/ that have not work.is some issue in website? some time show a error 301 Moved Parmanentaly. Some time laod a few lines of web sites. some time show a maximum execution time exceeded.

Comment: show on browser  "We're offline for a tune-up, we'll be up and running smoothly very soon.In the meantime, here are some other options available:"